# Not changing value in database when form is changed

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I click on save the maintenance value if I click yes changes to saves to db 1 and and 0 for no.

But now it is stuck on 1 for some reason and will not change config maintenance row value from 1 to 0

**Controller**

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Setting extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('user');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->lang->load('english', 'english');
        $this->lang->load('setting/setting', 'english');
        $this->load->model('setting/model_setting');
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE) {
         redirect('/');
      }
    }

    public function index() {

        $data['title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

        if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {

            $this->model_setting->editSetting('config', $this->input->post());

            redirect('store');
        }

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

        $data['text_yes'] = $this->lang->line('text_yes');
        $data['text_no'] = $this->lang->line('text_no');

        $data['entry_maintenance'] = $this->lang->line('entry_maintenance');

        $data['help_maintenance'] = $this->lang->line('help_maintenance');

        $data['button_save'] = $this->lang->line('button_save');
        $data['button_cancel'] = $this->lang->line('button_cancel');

        $data['tab_general'] = $this->lang->line('tab_general');
        $data['tab_server'] = $this->lang->line('tab_server');

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->lang->line('text_home'),
            'href' => site_url('dashboard')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->lang->line('heading_title'),
            'href' => site_url('setting')
        );

        $data['action'] = site_url('setting');

        if (null !==($this->input->post('config_maintenance'))) {
            $data['config_maintenance'] = $this->input->post('config_maintenance');
        } else {
            $data['config_maintenance'] = $this->input->get('config_maintenance');
        }

        $this->load->view('setting/setting', $data);
    }

    public function validate() {

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php 
class Model_setting extends CI_Model {

    public function getSetting($group, $store_id = 0) {
        $data = array(); 

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting 
            WHERE store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "' AND `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . "
        ");

        foreach ($query->row() as $result) {
            if (!$result['serialized']) {
                $data[$result['key']] = $result['value'];
            } else {
                $data[$result['key']] = unserialize($result['value']);
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function editSetting($group, $data, $store_id = 0) {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting 
            WHERE store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "' AND `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . "
        ");

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting 
                    SET store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "', 
                    `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . ", 
                    `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . ", 
                    `value` = " . $this->db->escape($value) . "
            ");
            } else {
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting 
                    SET store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "', 
                    `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . ", 
                    `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) .", 
                    `value` = " . $this->db->escape(serialize($value)) . ", 
                    serialized = '1'
                ");
            }
        }
    }

    public function editSettingValue($group = '', $key = '', $value = '', $store_id = 0) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting SET `
                value` = ". $this->db->escape($value) ." 
                WHERE `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) . " 
                AND `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . " AND store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "'");
        } else {
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting SET `
                value` = ". $this->db->escape(serialize($value)) ." 
                WHERE `group` = ". $this->db->escape($group) ." 
                AND `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . " AND store_id = '" . (int)$store_id . "' 
                AND serialized = '1'");
        }
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't say for certain but It looks as though you don't have any checks on your function call of the editSettings function:

`if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')`

You should maybe add a URL variable or a "delete?" Check box to check to make sure it is set as a conformation that you want to delete something. With this function call, every time the form is submitted regardless of any values in the form this editSettings function is called and will delete things.

Comment: I do not need to have it checked not a requirement

Comment: well then I'm not sure of your issue. You stated that rows were being deleted from the table on submit and that was the issue, based on your only `DELETE FROM` statement that would be expected, and I would like to point out that I take it as rude of you to -1 your first and still only response just because the question was misunderstood, the time was still taken to attempt to answer your question.

Comment: I changed if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') && $this->validate()) and stoped deleting rows. but when I click on the save button it does not change config_maintenance value from 1 to 0 zero meaning maintenance off

Comment: So the validation fixed the initial issue but it caused another issue?

Comment: Yes. Not changing the value from 1 to 0 and not redirecting after save. config maintenance does not need any validation checks, I have created function below index called public function validate()